# XSLT to return string between two characters

Tags: xslt, between

I am trying to return part of a string in an XML sheet.
I want to keep what is between the brackets in the "Description" field, and move what is outside the brackets to a different field:

The Source XML:

```
<Log>
   <Date>15-Nov-2014</Date>
   <TC>14:38:47:13</TC>
   <Description>Move this text (but keep this text here)</Description>
</Log>
```

Desired result is:

```
<Log>
   <Date>15-Nov-2014</Date>
   <TC>14:38:47:13</TC>
   <Description>but keep this text here</Description>
   <MyOtherField>Move this text</MyOtherField> 
</Log>
```

I have tried using the substring-before "(" and 'substring-after ")" functions in line and the output is almost correct - however the snag is that not all the "Description" fields in my source XML sheet have text in brackets, so those are being deleted completely.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "*not all the "Description" fields in my source XML sheet have text in brackets*" What is the expected result in such case?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response.  In this case we want the "Move this text" to still move and the "Description" field to therefore be empty.  
For example:
  
`    <Log>
           <Date>15-Nov-2014</Date>
           <TC>14:38:47:13</TC>
           <Description></Description>
           <MyOtherField>Move this text</MyOtherField> 
     </Log>`

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted as well?

Comment: Well, im using MapForce and the part of the XSLT it has generated is this:

`<Description>
    <xsl:sequence select="fn:substring-after(fn:substring-before(fn:string(Description), ')'), '(')"/>
</Description>`

However, this is deleting any instances where there isnt a section of text in brackets, where as I explained above, this needs to be kept.

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '('), ')')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <MyOtherField>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(., '('), '(')"/>
    </MyOtherField>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you could use `xsl:analyze-string` to get the text between the parens...

**XML Input**

```
<Log>
    <Date>15-Nov-2014</Date>
    <TC>14:38:47:13</TC>
    <Description>Move this text (but keep this text here)</Description>
</Log>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(([^)]+)\)">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:copy>
      <MyOtherField>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join((substring-before(concat(.,'('),'('),
          substring-after(.,')')),' '))"/>
      </MyOtherField>      
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Log>
   <Date>15-Nov-2014</Date>
   <TC>14:38:47:13</TC>
   <Description>but keep this text here</Description>
   <MyOtherField>Move this text</MyOtherField>
</Log>
```

Here it is integrated into your existing code: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifq1/1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Description[contains(text(), '(')]">
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., ' ('), ')')" />
        </Description>
        <MyOtherField>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' (')" />
        </MyOtherField>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that it may not work as expected if you have multiple `(`s or `)`s.  The idea is that you match any `Description` tags that contain a `(` in them, and then use the substring logic.

http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfU

Comment: amazing - thanks both for your guidance.

I am struggling to integrate this into my existing code generated by MapForce, would you be able to assist?

Here is a link to my existing code:

[http://xsltransform.net/pPzifq1](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifq1)

To clarify, any text in brackets needs to stay in the Description field, and any text outside a bracket must move to this keyword field.
`<Keyword Type="Keyword">MOVE THIS TEXT</Keyword>`

Comment: Use an `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose` with the `test` condition being what I put in as the `match` condition in my second template around your Description/Keyword nodes.